# HTTP 1.1 server sending large files

Tags: multithreading, http, threadpool

I've read an article about serving a lot of clients with a custom HTTP 1.1 server. It said that one needs to utilize a thread pool with as many threads as there are CPU cores, not spawn a new thread for each request. But, say a file is 1 GB long. It's transfer would halt one of the queues in the thread pool, while the file is being transferred, halting the processing of new requests. Surely a thread is spawned when transferring such files? But what criterion is applied to determine whether a new thread is to be spawned to serve a request, file size? Or some other? Perhaps some form of cooperative multitasking is used?

Comment: Why would you spawn a new thread when you have a pool?

Comment: @SMA say you have 4 cores, this means, say, 4 queues in the thread pool. The GB file halts one the 4 queues, since it takes a long time to transfer the file, leaving 3 to process http requests. If you spawn a new thread 4 queues are free to process requests.

Comment: Writing a custom HTTP server is a very very hard task (just read section 3.3.3 and 6 of rfc7230). Maybe you should check for nginx or Apache 2.4 mpm_event which already manage this sort of thread management and tcp/ip event loops. Or even golang http handlers.

Comment: @regilero there exist many simple implementations, my question is conceptual, I just suspect there must be some form of cooperative multitasking used as spawning countless threads, even if they are reused as part of a thread pool, seems counterproductive to me.

Comment: ideas around the event loops are you should nto even let the threads handle the in/out tcp/ip things, you wake up worker threads only when some other dedicated *things* have extracted the complete requests. So I'm pretty sure no worker thread should manage the file transfer, that's a job for a very specific high performance loop managing all the multiple tcp/ip streams in parallel. This should not prevent workers from processing other requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One queue per core would be a bad design. Normally, there's one queue for each pool thread and a global queue. Threads check their queue first, then the global queue, then other thread's queues. No work will become stuck.

You can use blocking and non-blocking IO in a mixed way in the same HTTP server. Most requests complete quickly, so there's not much point in using non-blocking IO.

It can be a good idea to make long-running requests use non-blocking IO in order to not hold up too many threads. The 1GB file transfer certainly sounds like a good case for that.

Socket IO in an HTTP server usually should be non-blocking. HTTP servers are often run under the assumption of many connected clients and long-standing connections. Making this scale almost requires non-blocking IO. But note, that although the network side should be non-blocking it is not architecturally required to make request processing non-blocking as well.

There are many outdated designs for socket servers (both implementations as well as tutorials). Using modern APIs and a modern design it really is not too hard to achieve scalability and good code quality.

Comment: one queue for each pool thread, but why would I spawn more pool threads than there a hardware cores? Why the global queue? You realize that if you check other thread's queues you may need to lock them first?

Comment: Threads can block, so in order to saturate the CPU it's common to have a little (or a lot more). Not all IO is/should be non-blocking. The global queue is optional, it can promote fairness for certain work itemss. The local queues must be accessed in a synchronized way. There is no way around that if you don't want items stuck behind a head of line blocker (as you mentioned). Most apps are not 100% loaded, so unevenly filled thread queues are extremely common.

Comment: If you want a good, modern example for how this works look at .NET. It has a thread pool as I described it and it uses Windows IOCP for it's non-blocking IO. Blocking and non-blocking play well together. It's just all one big thread pool. Non-blocking IOs do not block a thread. IO completions are posted as TP work items.